# Multiple Complex Select in One Reusable Expression c# LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, expression

Is there a way to make a single expression that does a complex select.  I need to select a row from my contact table which is the first item from a candidate table joined to the contact.

```cs
dbContext.Contacts.Where( x=> x.ContactId == 9566)
    .Select( x=> new { Candidate = x.Candidates.FirstOrDefault(), Contact = x})
    .Select( x=>  new  
                {
                    ContactId = x.Contact.ContactId,
                    UserTitleId = x.Contact.UserTitleId,
                    Forename = x.Contact.ForeName,
                    MiddleName = x.Contact.MiddleName,
                    Surname = x.Contact.Surname,

                    CandidateId = x.Candidate.CandidateId,
                    TeacherRefNum = x.Candidate.TeacherRefNum,
                    DateOfBirth = x.Candidate.DateOfBirth
                })
```

As there could be multiple candidates but I just want the first one I need to do a FirstOrDefault.  If that is applied for every parameter the SQL generated seems very inefficient.  So the following expression is not good

```cs
 public static Expression<Func<Contact, CandidateM>> ToM()
            {
                return x =>   new CandidateM 
                {
                    ContactId = x.ContactId,
                    UserTitleId = x.UserTitleId,
                    Forename = x.ForeName,
                    MiddleName = x.MiddleName,
                    Surname = x.Surname

                    CandidateId = x.Candidate.FirstOrDefault().CandidateId,
                    TeacherRefNum = x.Candidate.FirstOrDefault().TeacherRefNum,
                    DateOfBirth = x.Candidate.FirstOrDefault().DateOfBirth

                };
            }
```

I would like to generate a single Expression that I can use on the contact table as a select does this efficiently.

```cs
DbContext.Contact.Where( x=> x.ContactId == id ).Select(CandidateM.ToM()).FirstOrDefault();
```

The SQL that is produced by the expression I did above with the multiple FirstOrDefault methods looks like the below. Given I want to get even more structure from this such as selecting all dress fields from the candidate I think it may not be the best way of doing things.  Perhaps this humungus SQL query that LINQ to Entities produces is not that much of an issue though?

```sql
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
    [Limit6].[ContactId] AS [ContactId], 
    [Limit6].[C8] AS [C1], 
    [Limit6].[UserTitleId] AS [UserTitleId], 
    [Limit6].[ForeName] AS [ForeName], 
    [Limit6].[MiddleName] AS [MiddleName], 
    [Limit6].[Surname] AS [Surname], 
    [Limit6].[PreviousSurname] AS [PreviousSurname], 
    [Limit6].[KnownAs] AS [KnownAs], 
    [Limit6].[C9] AS [C2], 
    [Limit6].[C10] AS [C3], 
    [Limit6].[C11] AS [C4], 
    [Limit6].[C12] AS [C5], 
    [Limit6].[Email] AS [Email], 
    [Limit6].[WorkPhone] AS [WorkPhone], 
    [Limit6].[PersonalPhone] AS [PersonalPhone], 
    [Limit6].[Mobile] AS [Mobile], 
    [Limit6].[C1] AS [C6], 
    [Limit6].[C2] AS [C7], 
    [Limit6].[C3] AS [C8], 
    [Limit6].[C4] AS [C9], 
    [Limit6].[C5] AS [C10], 
    [Limit6].[C6] AS [C11], 
    [Limit6].[C7] AS [C12]
    FROM ( SELECT TOP (1) 
        [Project14].[ContactId] AS [ContactId], 
        [Project14].[UserTitleId] AS [UserTitleId], 
        [Project14].[ForeName] AS [ForeName], 
        [Project14].[MiddleName] AS [MiddleName], 
        [Project14].[Surname] AS [Surname], 
        [Project14].[KnownAs] AS [KnownAs], 
        [Project14].[PreviousSurname] AS [PreviousSurname], 
        [Extent7].[Email] AS [Email], 
        [Extent7].[Mobile] AS [Mobile], 
        [Extent7].[WorkPhone] AS [WorkPhone], 
        [Extent7].[PersonalPhone] AS [PersonalPhone], 
        N'''' AS [C1], 
        N'''' AS [C2], 
        N'''' AS [C3], 
        N'''' AS [C4], 
        N'''' AS [C5], 
        N'''' AS [C6], 
        1 AS [C7], 
        [Project14].[C1] AS [C8], 
        [Project14].[C2] AS [C9], 
        [Project14].[C3] AS [C10], 
        [Project14].[C4] AS [C11], 
        [Project14].[C5] AS [C12]
        FROM   (SELECT 
            [Project12].[ContactId] AS [ContactId], 
            [Project12].[UserTitleId] AS [UserTitleId], 
            [Project12].[ForeName] AS [ForeName], 
            [Project12].[MiddleName] AS [MiddleName], 
            [Project12].[Surname] AS [Surname], 
            [Project12].[KnownAs] AS [KnownAs], 
            [Project12].[PreviousSurname] AS [PreviousSurname], 
            [Project12].[C1] AS [C1], 
            [Project12].[C2] AS [C2], 
            [Project12].[C3] AS [C3], 
            [Project12].[C4] AS [C4], 
            (SELECT TOP (1) 
                [Extent6].[JobTitle] AS [JobTitle]
                FROM [dbo].[Candidate] AS [Extent6]
                WHERE [Project12].[ContactId] = [Extent6].[ContactId]) AS [C5]
            FROM ( SELECT 
                [Project11].[ContactId] AS [ContactId], 
                [Project11].[UserTitleId] AS [UserTitleId], 
                [Project11].[ForeName] AS [ForeName], 
                [Project11].[MiddleName] AS [MiddleName], 
                [Project11].[Surname] AS [Surname], 
                [Project11].[KnownAs] AS [KnownAs], 
                [Project11].[PreviousSurname] AS [PreviousSurname], 
                [Project11].[C1] AS [C1], 
                [Project11].[C2] AS [C2], 
                [Project11].[C3] AS [C3], 
                [Project11].[C4] AS [C4]
                FROM ( SELECT 
                    [Project9].[ContactId] AS [ContactId], 
                    [Project9].[UserTitleId] AS [UserTitleId], 
                    [Project9].[ForeName] AS [ForeName], 
                    [Project9].[MiddleName] AS [MiddleName], 
                    [Project9].[Surname] AS [Surname], 
                    [Project9].[KnownAs] AS [KnownAs], 
                    [Project9].[PreviousSurname] AS [PreviousSurname], 
                    [Project9].[C1] AS [C1], 
                    [Project9].[C2] AS [C2], 
                    [Project9].[C3] AS [C3], 
                    (SELECT TOP (1) 
                        [Extent5].[NINumber] AS [NINumber]
                        FROM [dbo].[Candidate] AS [Extent5]
                        WHERE [Project9].[ContactId] = [Extent5].[ContactId]) AS [C4]
                    FROM ( SELECT 
                        [Project8].[ContactId] AS [ContactId], 
                        [Project8].[UserTitleId] AS [UserTitleId], 
                        [Project8].[ForeName] AS [ForeName], 
                        [Project8].[MiddleName] AS [MiddleName], 
                        [Project8].[Surname] AS [Surname], 
                        [Project8].[KnownAs] AS [KnownAs], 
                        [Project8].[PreviousSurname] AS [PreviousSurname], 
                        [Project8].[C1] AS [C1], 
                        [Project8].[C2] AS [C2], 
                        [Project8].[C3] AS [C3]
                        FROM ( SELECT 
                            [Project6].[ContactId] AS [ContactId], 
                            [Project6].[UserTitleId] AS [UserTitleId], 
                            [Project6].[ForeName] AS [ForeName], 
                            [Project6].[MiddleName] AS [MiddleName], 
                            [Project6].[Surname] AS [Surname], 
                            [Project6].[KnownAs] AS [KnownAs], 
                            [Project6].[PreviousSurname] AS [PreviousSurname], 
                            [Project6].[C1] AS [C1], 
                            [Project6].[C2] AS [C2], 
                            (SELECT TOP (1) 
                                [Extent4].[DateOfBirth] AS [DateOfBirth]
                                FROM [dbo].[Candidate] AS [Extent4]
                                WHERE [Project6].[ContactId] = [Extent4].[ContactId]) AS [C3]
                            FROM ( SELECT 
                                [Project5].[ContactId] AS [ContactId], 
                                [Project5].[UserTitleId] AS [UserTitleId], 
                                [Project5].[ForeName] AS [ForeName], 
                                [Project5].[MiddleName] AS [MiddleName], 
                                [Project5].[Surname] AS [Surname], 
                                [Project5].[KnownAs] AS [KnownAs], 
                                [Project5].[PreviousSurname] AS [PreviousSurname], 
                                [Project5].[C1] AS [C1], 
                                [Project5].[C2] AS [C2]
                                FROM ( SELECT 
                                    [Project3].[ContactId] AS [ContactId], 
                                    [Project3].[UserTitleId] AS [UserTitleId], 
                                    [Project3].[ForeName] AS [ForeName], 
                                    [Project3].[MiddleName] AS [MiddleName], 
                                    [Project3].[Surname] AS [Surname], 
                                    [Project3].[KnownAs] AS [KnownAs], 
                                    [Project3].[PreviousSurname] AS [PreviousSurname], 
                                    [Project3].[C1] AS [C1], 
                                    (SELECT TOP (1) 
                                        [Extent3].[TeacherRefNum] AS [TeacherRefNum]
                                        FROM [dbo].[Candidate] AS [Extent3]
                                        WHERE [Project3].[ContactId] = [Extent3].[ContactId]) AS [C2]
                                    FROM ( SELECT 
                                        [Project2].[ContactId] AS [ContactId], 
                                        [Project2].[UserTitleId] AS [UserTitleId], 
                                        [Project2].[ForeName] AS [ForeName], 
                                        [Project2].[MiddleName] AS [MiddleName], 
                                        [Project2].[Surname] AS [Surname], 
                                        [Project2].[KnownAs] AS [KnownAs], 
                                        [Project2].[PreviousSurname] AS [PreviousSurname], 
                                        [Project2].[C1] AS [C1]
                                        FROM ( SELECT 
                                            [Extent1].[ContactId] AS [ContactId], 
                                            [Extent1].[UserTitleId] AS [UserTitleId], 
                                            [Extent1].[ForeName] AS [ForeName], 
                                            [Extent1].[MiddleName] AS [MiddleName], 
                                            [Extent1].[Surname] AS [Surname], 
                                            [Extent1].[KnownAs] AS [KnownAs], 
                                            [Extent1].[PreviousSurname] AS [PreviousSurname], 
                                            (SELECT TOP (1) 
                                                [Extent2].[CandidateId] AS [CandidateId]
                                                FROM [dbo].[Candidate] AS [Extent2]
                                                WHERE [Extent1].[ContactId] = [Extent2].[ContactId]) AS [C1]
                                            FROM [dbo].[Contact] AS [Extent1]
                                            WHERE [Extent1].[ContactId] = @p__linq__0
                                        )  AS [Project2]
                                    )  AS [Project3]
                                )  AS [Project5]
                            )  AS [Project6]
                        )  AS [Project8]
                    )  AS [Project9]
                )  AS [Project11]
            )  AS [Project12] ) AS [Project14]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[ContactExtended] AS [Extent7] ON [Project14].[ContactId] = [Extent7].[ContactId]
    )  AS [Limit6]',N'@p__linq__0 int',@p__linq__0=9566
```

Comment: So what is wrong with the code you show here? When you say "efficiently", what exactly do you mean?

Comment: *seems very inefficient.* -- Well, did you actually check the generated SQL? I don't think it's inefficient at all.

Comment: @GertArnold The SQL that is produced by this expression is not pretty.  I have added it to the post above.  It is in fact worse now as I have also included the address that is a child of "Candidate". The problem is the SQL seems to have a nested select for each field when you use FirstOrDefault multiple times.  Each select is nested under the previous fields select.  Not only does it do this but for some reason all of the fields fo contact are brought into the select again as well.

Comment: @DavidG Hi, see comment above and the SQL I included.